# On linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $F[x]$ be the space of all polynomials over the field $F$. Prove that, if $L$ is any linear functional on $F[x]$ such that

$L(fg)=L(f)L(g),$ for all $f,g\in F[x]$,

then either $L=0$ or there is a $t$ in $F$ such that $L(f)=f(t)$ for all $f$.

All I can think of is perhaps the proof is to be done by contradiction. I need help on this please.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $L(1) = 0$. Then $L(p(x)) = L(1 * p(x)) = L(1) * L(p(x)) = 0$.
Hence $L$ is the zero functional.

Assume $L \neq 0$, then $L(1) \neq 0$ by the above remark. Since $L(1) = L(1*1) = L(1) * L(1)$ we conclude $L(1)=1$. $L$ is linear, therefore we have $L(a) = a$ for any $a \in F$.

Now, let $t = L(x)$. Then, since $L$ respects multiplication and addition (in technical terms, $L$ is an $F-$algebra homomorphism) we have for $ p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$
\begin{equation}
L(p(x)) = L(a_0) + L(a_1) L(x) + \cdots + L(a_n) L(x)^n = a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_n t^n = p(t).
\end{equation}

Comment: This is really helpful @Georg Lehner. But what is really not very clear to me is the assumption you made, that $L(1)=0$.

Comment: $L$ maps $1$ to $0$ if and only if $L(1) = 0$. I showed this first, because $L(1) = L(1) * L(1)$ is also true if $L(1) = 0$. If we however know, that $L(1) = 0$ only for the zero map, then we can conclude for every non-zero $L$ from $L(1) = L(1) * L(1)$ that $L(1) = 1$ by dividing by $L(1)$.

Comment: so to be clear, t does not have to be in F right? it can be a polynomial. For example, L(f) = f(x^2) has the multiplicative property. The confusion is i think that the hoffman and kunze problem that this question is based on says that t must be in F, which is wrong

Comment: @Auburn: A linear functional is defined to have values in $F$. $f(x) \mapsto f(x^2)$ is certainly multiplicative, but it is a linear map to $F[x]$, not $F$. There is something deeper going on though: For any $F$-algebra $A$, the set of $F$-linear, multiplicative functions from $F[x]$ to $A$ is given by the set $A$ plus the constant zero function. In more sophisticated language, $F[x]$ is the free $F$-algebra on one generator.